# Dúvida sobre FK, banco de dados Visual Studio

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Olá, criei três tabelas em um banco de dados no Visual Studio, as duas primeiras (`clientes` e `produtos`) são tabelas normais com primary key na coluna `Nome`. Em seguida criei a tabela `compras` que iria ter dus FK, uma pra tabela `clientes` e outra para `produtos` indicando o campo `Nome` de cada uma, ficando assim o código da tabela (no Visual):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[comprar]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Data de compra] DATETIME NULL, 
    [Cliente] NCHAR(100) NULL, 
    [Produto] NCHAR(100) NULL, 
    [Entrega] DATETIME NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_comprar_ToCliente] FOREIGN KEY ([Cliente]) REFERENCES [clientes]([Nome]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_comprar_ToProduto] FOREIGN KEY ([Produto]) REFERENCES [produtos]([Nome]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Mas, ao testar constatei que os campos `Cliente` e `Produto` dessa tabela continua aceitando qualquer valor, mesmo que ele não esteja na tabela `clientes` ou `produtos`. Queria saber como deixo esses campos da tabela como um ComboBox ou parecido, dando as opções apenas dos registros cadastrados nas tabelas indicadas? E também como alterar registros da tabela clientes e produtos assim que ele salar uma compra (exemplo, o cliente compra 5 tomates, daí ele diminui o campo de quantidade do registro tomate na tabela produtos e adiciona a compra feita a um campo do registro do cliente na tabela clientes)

**Tabela clientes**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[clientes] (
    [ID]         INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Nome]       NCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
    [CPF]        NCHAR (11)  NULL,
    [Email]      NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Telefone]   NCHAR (11)  NOT NULL,
    [Endereço]   NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Cidade]     NCHAR (15)  NOT NULL,
    [Comentário] NCHAR (500) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_clientes] PRIMARY KEY ([Nome])
);
```

**Tabela Produtos**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[produtos]
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY , 
    [Nome] NCHAR(150) NOT NULL, 
    [Quantidade] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Marca] NCHAR(100) NOT NULL,  
    [Comentário] NCHAR(500) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_produtos] PRIMARY KEY ([Nome])
)
```

Comment: Qual a PK das tabelas Cliente e Produtos ?

Comment: São várias perguntas num post só...Faltou dizer ou citar que está usando SQL Server, pois "Visual Studio" não é um banco de dados...você está modelando o BD por ele.

Comment: Banco de dados é SQL Server... PK em ambas as tabelas são a coluna Nome, pois o campo para FK deve ser obrigatoriamente a PK da outra tabela, e como queria que fosse feito com Nome coloquei Nome

Comment: 1 Não é usual um campo deste tipo ser PK , o problema pode estar aí. 2 O conteúdo de nome deveria estar exato a como está na Pk 3 Outra coisa é verificar se as constraints de fk e/ou pk estão "enabled" PKs e FKs.

Comment: Poste também a descricão das outras tabelas

Comment: Acrescentei o código das outras tabelas, estão como enabled.. Vi um vídeo no YouTube e testei em outro projeto e depois nesse, o FK está funcionando, mas no programa ele não dá mensagem de erro quando não acha registro igual ao que foi indicado no campo `cliente` ou `produto` e o aceita

Answer (score 2):

Repare que o tamanho dos campos diferem 150 x 100, e sendo nchar (tamanho fixo) isto gera uma diferença.

Tente usar o ID como chave nas tabelas (ou um campo único como CPF , código de barras etc) e use um campo de mesmo tipo e tamanho como FK, esta a prática mais comum em modelagem

Usando o nome como chave você ainda teria outro problema , poderia haver dois "Leonardo Villarinho" e seu sistema só permitiria um cadastro.